# How to customize the step of a number input field?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, input-field

I have an input field of type `number` which ranges from `1` to `4096` as follows:

---

```
<input max="4096" min="1" name="size" step="2" type="number" value="4096">
```

[image: Input field of type number]

---

Iam currently using a `step = 2`, that result in numbers `2, 4, 6, 8, 10, ...`

### How can I modify the step to double the value `1 , 2, 4, 8, 16,...`?

---

***Note***:

The field can contain only these values (The user shoudn't be able to insert  `3 , 5 , 6, 7, ...`). And it should work on both increment and decrement.

Comment: This would be confusing, since it differs from how number input widgets on web pages in general. Consider using a `select` element instead, with a suitable set of `option` values.

Comment: I have other fields with even bigger range, I don't want the user to select from dropdown with 2000 items .I'm trying to know if there is a solution out of the box.

Comment: I guess you'll need javascript for that.

Comment: If you think a “double the value” functionality is useful, consider using a simple text input field with JavaScript-driven buttons for doubling the value and JavaScript checks for the value being one of the accepted values (in case the user just types in something).

Comment: I was trying to avoid adding too much logic in a simple field. But this seems to be my only option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The native stepper doesn't suit your requirements. Your best bet would be to implement a custom solution.

I put together an example. Have a look at it:

```js
$('.steps').text($('.steps').data('min'));

$('.step').click(function() {
  if ($('.steps').text() == 1 && $(this).hasClass('down') ||
    +$('.steps').data("max") == +$('.steps').text() &&
    $(this).hasClass('up'))
    return;

  if ($(this).hasClass('up'))
    $('.steps').text($('.steps').text() * 2);
  else
    $('.steps').text($('.steps').text() / 2);
});
```

```css
.stepper {
  width: 75px;
  height: 30px;
  border: 1px solid #C0C0C0;
  display: inline-block;
}

.steps {
  width: 55px;
  float: left;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 30px;
}

.step {
  font-size: 8px;
  width: 20px;
  padding: 0px;
  float: right;
}

.step.up {
  vertical-align: top;
}

.step.down {
  vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="stepper">
  <span class="steps" data-min="1" data-max="4096"></span>
  <button type="button" class="step up">&#x25B2;</button>
  <button type="button" class="step down">&#x25BC;</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Replacing a native html element with a custom one build with a 'div' and 2 buttons could have major impact. 1 of them is accessibility. second, is semantics.

Answer (score 0):

I would use javascript to change your step dynamically on change

```
<input max="4096" min="1" name="size" step="2" type="number" value="4096" id="foo">

<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#foo').change(function(){
        this.step=this.value;
    });
</script>
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ltvj50e0/)

Comment: "this.step=this.value" is faster/simpler than " $('#foo').attr('step',$('#foo').val())"

Comment: it does the same thing as your code, just without un-needed overhead. the fiddle doesn't seem to work in either flavor, except going down oddly enough...

Comment: `onchange="this.step=this.value"`

Comment: I was seeking something out of the box, the solution you presented, does't handle decreasing the number.

Comment: @mohameddiaa27 what do you mean by _"out of the box"_? That is not how `step` works, so in that sense there will be no out-of-the-box solution.

Comment: apparently there is no solution out of the box. This solution works only on increasing the value.

Answer (score 0):

This works.

```js
$("#numbercruncher").change(function(){
  
  var a=parseInt($("#numbercruncher").val());
  var b =a*2-1;
  $("#numbercruncher").attr("step",b);
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="number" min="1" max="1000" id="numbercruncher"step="2">
```

Or this

```html
 <input type="number" min="1" max="2000" onchange="this.step=this.value*2-1">
```

Comment: Uses jQuery, but the question was not tagged with “jquery”. And does not work: second increment makes the value 2 and the field invalid in HTML and CSS terms (since you changed the `step` value).

Comment: 2nd code snippet doesn't use jquery. He wanted the step value to double each time, which is exactly what it does. why invalid html and css ?

Comment: The *field* is invalid as you can see e.g. by testing on Firefox (a red outline is displayed, as per the browser defaults for fields with invalid values). And if you can do it in a JavaScript one-liner, why present first a jQuery alternative?

Comment: Admitted I hadn't seen that jquery wasn't tagged, Scanned the page and saw jquery in the other answer. My bad.. After I posted I realised and had a look into other ways using pure js, hence the second answer. As for invalidating the html... ummm, maybe not adding a value field ??  Just gonna have a look and back in a mo

Comment: my bad, I can use jQuery. The thing is, this code works only for increasing the number.

Comment: isn't that what you wanted ??? I quote "How can I modify the step to double the value 1 , 2, 4, 8, 16,...?" EDIT## Just seen your comment below, You want to decrease aswell. Working on it

Answer (score -1):

This thread is old, but nowadays, just put step in the html tag:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1>The input step attribute</h1>

<form action="/action_page.php">
  <label for="points">Points:</label>
  <input type="number" id="points" name="points" step="0.2">
  <input type="submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Source: [W3CSchool](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_input_step)