# Conditional ngPattern

Tags: angularjs, ng-pattern, angularjs-ng-pattern

Following this bit of code:

```
    <label class="checkbox-label">
        <input name="radio1" type="radio"
               ng-model="myModel.radio" 
               required ng-required="true" 
               value="1">
    </label>
    <label class="checkbox-label">
        <input name="radio1" type="radio"
               ng-model="myModel.radio" 
               required ng-required="true"
               value="2">
    </label>

    <input type="number" name="result" class="form-control input-sm" ng-model="myModel.result"
        required ng-required="true" ng-pattern="/^[0-9]+(\.[0-9]{1,2})?$/" step="0.1" min="0" max="100">
```

i need to set the `ng-pattern` & `step` to accept one decimal place (0.1) or two decimal places (0.01) based on the `radio1` selection

Anyone has an idea how to approach this?

**UPDATE**
I have created a directive to do this, but validation is not triggered after changing the pattern (Angular 1.2)

```
app.directive('stepChange', function () {
    return {
        link: function link(scope, element, attr) {
            element.bind('change', function () {
                var el = angular.element(attr['target']);
                el.attr('step', attr['step']);
                el.attr('pattern', attr['pattern']);
                el.val(attr['val']);
                el.trigger();
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should write custom implementation for `step` and `pattern` to work dynamically.

**For Reference**

[How to customize the step of a number input field?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26852827/how-to-customize-the-step-of-a-number-input-field)

[HTML5 input type=number change step behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11738726/html5-input-type-number-change-step-behavior)

Answer (score 0):

The key to doing this is :

1. Apply watch on model used in radio.
2. Change step value in above watch and assign it back using scope variable

   > ```
   > $scope.$watch('myModel.radio',function(a,b){
   >      debugger
   >      if(a ==1){
   >         $scope.step = "0.1";
   >      }else if(a==2){
   >         $scope.step = "0.01";
   >      }
   >    });
   > ```

Please apply the step logic/values yourself in plunkr.

https://plnkr.co/edit/BKTS5jDTRoRQomNzHSt2?p=preview

You can also make the ng-pattern dynamic the same way(like step)

```
<input type="number" name="result" class="form-control input-sm" 
    ng-model="myModel.result" required ng-required="true" 
    ng-pattern="/^[0-9]+(\.[0-9]{1,2})?$/" step={{step}} min="0" max="100">
```

Comment: Please see update, this does not change the pattern validation.